# How do I tell GCC to link the C standard library, not the C++ one?

Tags: gcc, linker

I would like to statically link my C application against the C standard library that I have installed. I want to ensure that the C++ standard library is not linked.

I have tried passing `-nodefaultlibs`, but this also disables the C library.

How do I disable the C++ standard library and force C mode?

Comment: I just tested some C++ code on a file named "gcctest.c" and "gcctest.cpp"; it seems that GCC does not link the C++ standard library or include C++ headers if the file does not have the ".cpp" extension. So only using the ".c" extension for your C code might work.

Comment: Tell us why do you believe that your C application is being statically linked with the Standard C++ library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link with `gcc` instead of `g++`. `gcc` does not link in the standard library by default, unlike `g++`.